# What is the state of the art in 4-manfold 2-types?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, homotopy-theory, reference-request

In an [old answer to an old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35925/natural-examples-of-finite-dimensional-spaces-with-interesting-2-type/50835#50835), Peter Teichner commented that it is an open problem to determine which [homotopy 2-types](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+n-type) arise from 4-manifolds. In some instances we know that a 4-manifold *is* a 2-type with one extra piece of data (the intersection form), so it's a very interesting question as to when we can go the other way.

I'd like to know what is the latest on this problem, in the form of references or results.

Comment: When you say "in some instances", do you mean "in the simply connected case"?

Comment: No. There are nontrivial cases known for $\pi_1\not=0$.